# Error while trying to build Qt static with powershell script

Tags: powershell, qt, qt5

I've been trying to build Qt 5.14.1 static for quite some time now. I've been having a whole lot of trouble with it. I came across this powershell for it here (https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW) that keeps popping up. It is evidently outdated. There were some fixes to make it work. After applying them, i still get an error. My log doesnt seem to match any other i could find on the internet.

```
Building static Qt version 5.14.1
Using MinGW from C:\Qt\QtDynamic\Tools\mingw730_32
+ cd qtbase
+ C:\Qt\static\src\qt-everywhere-src-5.14.1\qtbase\configure.bat -top-level -static -debug-and-release -platform win32-g++ -prefix C:\Qt\Static\5.14.1         -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -qt-sql-sqlite -no-openssl         -opensource -confirm-license         -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests
 Please make sure to unset the QMAKESPEC, XQMAKESPEC, QMAKEPATH,
 and QMAKEFEATURES environment variables prior to building Qt.
mingw32-make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.
Out-File : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Qt\Static\5.14.1\mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf'.
At C:\Qt\static\windows-build-qt-static.ps1:178 char:6
+ "@ | Out-File -Append $File -Encoding Ascii
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

Press Enter to continue...:
```

I'm not too sure what to make of it. Anyone have any idea?

I've also tried building it a few different ways but i get errors regardless. When building with mingw, i get this

```
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -Wno-expansion-to-defined -Wno-c++0x-compat -msse2 -mstackrealign -mfpmath=sse -O2 -std=c++1z -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wextra -Wextra -Wno-expansion-to-defined -Wvla -Wdate-time -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wduplicated-cond -Wno-stringop-overflow -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -DQT_NO_LINKED_LIST -DQT_NO_LINKED_LIST -DQT_NO_JAVA_STYLE_ITERATORS -DQT_NO_URL_CAST_FROM_STRING -DQT_NO_INTEGER_EVENT_COORDINATES -DQT_NO_FOREACH -DWTF_EXPORT_PRIVATE= -DJS_EXPORT_PRIVATE= -DENABLE_ASSEMBLER_WX_EXCLUSIVE=1 -DWTFReportAssertionFailure=qmlWTFReportAssertionFailure -DWTFReportAssertionFailureWithMessage=qmlWTFReportAssertionFailureWithMessage -DWTFReportBacktrace=qmlWTFReportBacktrace -DWTFInvokeCrashHook=qmlWTFInvokeCrashHook -DNOMINMAX -DENABLE_LLINT=0 -DENABLE_DFG_JIT=0 -DENABLE_DFG_JIT_UTILITY_METHODS=1 -DENABLE_JIT_CONSTANT_BLINDING=0 -DBUILDING_QT__ -DWTF_USE_UDIS86=0 -DNDEBUG -DQT_NO_NARROWING_CONVERSIONS_IN_CONNECT -DQT_BUILD_QML_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS_SINCE=0x060000 -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -Imemory -I. -Icompiler -I. -Ijsruntime -I. -Ijit -I. -Idebugger -Iqmldirparser -I. -Ianimations -I..\3rdparty\masm\jit -I..\3rdparty\masm\assembler -I..\3rdparty\masm\runtime -I..\3rdparty\masm\wtf -I..\3rdparty\masm\stubs -I..\3rdparty\masm\stubs\runtime -I..\3rdparty\masm\stubs\wtf -I..\3rdparty\masm -I..\3rdparty\masm\disassembler -I..\3rdparty\masm\disassembler\udis86 -I.generated -I..\..\include -I..\..\include\QtQml -I..\..\include\QtQml\5.14.1 -I..\..\include\QtQml\5.14.1\QtQml -Itmp -I. -I.tracegen -IC:\Qt\static\qt\qtbase\include\QtCore\5.14.1 -IC:\Qt\static\qt\qtbase\include\QtCore\5.14.1\QtCore -IC:\Qt\static\qt\qtbase\include -IC:\Qt\static\qt\qtbase\include\QtNetwork -IC:\Qt\static\qt\qtbase\include\QtCore -I.moc -IC:\Qt\static\qt\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-g++  -o .obj\qqmlpropertymap.o util\qqmlpropertymap.cpp
g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
mingw32-make[3]: *** [Makefile:10581: .obj/qqmlpropertymap.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/static/qt/qtdeclarative/src/qml'
mingw32-make[2]: *** [Makefile:61: sub-qml-make_first-ordered] Error 2
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/static/qt/qtdeclarative/src'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile:53: sub-src-make_first] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/static/qt/qtdeclarative'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:342: module-qtdeclarative-make_first] Error 2
```

The solution i found to that error was "use the powershell script" which brought me here.

qtbase folder:

```
01/24/2020  03:24    <DIR>          .
01/24/2020  03:24    <DIR>          ..
01/23/2020  08:37               177 .qmake.conf
01/24/2020  03:24            80,874 .QT-ENTERPRISE-LICENSE-AGREEMENT
01/24/2020  03:24            80,874 .QT-FOR-APPLICATION-DEVELOPMENT-LICENSE-AGREEMENT
01/24/2020  03:24            80,874 .QT-FOR-AUTOMATION-LICENSE-AGREEMENT
01/24/2020  03:24            47,369 .QT-FOR-AUTOMOTIVE-LICENSE-AGREEMENT
01/24/2020  03:24            80,874 .QT-FOR-DEVICE-CREATION-LICENSE-AGREEMENT
01/24/2020  03:23                29 .release-timestamp
01/23/2020  08:37                42 .tag
01/24/2020  03:24    <DIR>          bin
01/23/2020  08:37    <DIR>          config.tests
01/23/2020  08:37            27,796 configure
01/23/2020  08:37             8,180 configure.bat
01/23/2020  08:37            60,674 configure.json
01/23/2020  08:37            53,355 configure.pri
01/23/2020  08:37            17,564 config_help.txt
01/23/2020  08:37    <DIR>          dist
01/23/2020  08:37    <DIR>          doc
01/23/2020  08:37    <DIR>          examples
01/23/2020  08:37             2,507 header.BSD
01/23/2020  08:37               825 header.COMM
01/23/2020  08:37             1,283 header.FDL
01/23/2020  08:37             1,370 header.GPL
01/23/2020  08:37             1,300 header.GPL-EXCEPT
01/23/2020  08:37             1,957 header.LGPL
01/23/2020  08:37             1,847 header.LGPL-NOGPL2
01/23/2020  08:37               959 header.LGPL-ONLY
01/23/2020  08:37             1,758 header.LGPL3
01/23/2020  08:37             1,306 header.LGPL3-COMM
01/23/2020  08:37             1,454 header.MIT
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          include
01/23/2020  08:37               458 INSTALL
01/23/2020  08:37    <DIR>          lib
01/23/2020  08:37            23,411 LICENSE.FDL
01/23/2020  08:37            18,431 LICENSE.GPL2
01/23/2020  08:37            35,821 LICENSE.GPL3
01/23/2020  08:37            37,067 LICENSE.GPL3-EXCEPT
01/23/2020  08:37             7,816 LICENSE.LGPL3
01/23/2020  08:37             8,348 LICENSE.LGPLv3
01/23/2020  08:37            80,874 LICENSE.QT-LICENSE-AGREEMENT
01/23/2020  08:37    <DIR>          mkspecs
01/23/2020  08:37    <DIR>          qmake
01/23/2020  08:37             2,716 qtbase.pro
01/23/2020  08:37    <DIR>          src
01/23/2020  08:37             4,898 sync.profile
01/23/2020  08:37    <DIR>          tests
01/23/2020  08:37    <DIR>          util
              34 File(s)        775,088 bytes
              14 Dir(s)   2,796,851,200 bytes free
```

parent directory:

```
01/24/2020  03:38    <DIR>          .
01/24/2020  03:38    <DIR>          ..
01/24/2020  03:38             7,309 .gitmodules
01/24/2020  03:23            80,874 .QT-ENTERPRISE-LICENSE-AGREEMENT
01/24/2020  03:23            80,874 .QT-FOR-APPLICATION-DEVELOPMENT-LICENSE-AGREEMENT
01/24/2020  03:23            80,874 .QT-FOR-AUTOMATION-LICENSE-AGREEMENT
01/24/2020  03:23            47,369 .QT-FOR-AUTOMOTIVE-LICENSE-AGREEMENT
01/24/2020  03:23            80,874 .QT-FOR-DEVICE-CREATION-LICENSE-AGREEMENT
01/24/2020  03:38                40 .tag
01/24/2020  01:22    <DIR>          coin
01/24/2020  01:22             1,984 configure
01/24/2020  01:22             2,033 configure.bat
01/24/2020  01:22               101 configure.json
01/24/2020  01:22    <DIR>          gnuwin32
01/24/2020  01:22            23,411 LICENSE.FDL
01/24/2020  01:22            15,643 LICENSE.GPLv2
01/24/2020  01:22            36,327 LICENSE.GPLv3
01/24/2020  01:22            27,342 LICENSE.LGPLv21
01/24/2020  01:22             8,349 LICENSE.LGPLv3
01/24/2020  01:22            80,874 LICENSE.QT-LICENSE-AGREEMENT
01/24/2020  01:22             3,065 qt.pro
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qt3d
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtactiveqt
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtandroidextras
01/24/2020  03:24    <DIR>          qtbase
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtcharts
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtconnectivity
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtdatavis3d
01/24/2020  03:24    <DIR>          qtdeclarative
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtdoc
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtgamepad
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtgraphicaleffects
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtimageformats
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtlocation
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtlottie
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtmacextras
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtmultimedia
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtnetworkauth
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtpurchasing
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtquick3d
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtquickcontrols
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtquickcontrols2
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtquicktimeline
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtremoteobjects
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtscript
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtscxml
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtsensors
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtserialbus
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtserialport
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtspeech
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtsvg
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qttools
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qttranslations
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtvirtualkeyboard
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtwayland
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtwebchannel
01/24/2020  03:24    <DIR>          qtwebengine
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtwebglplugin
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtwebsockets
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtwebview
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtwinextras
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtx11extras
01/24/2020  03:23    <DIR>          qtxmlpatterns
01/24/2020  01:22             3,976 README
01/24/2020  01:22             2,926 _clang-format
              19 File(s)        584,245 bytes
              46 Dir(s)   2,796,638,208 bytes free

C:\Qt\static\src\qt-everywhere-src-5.14.1>
```

Comment: Are you sure the source is correct? Did you actually download Qt modules? Check the directory to ensure that Qt modules have been downloaded.

Comment: What this error suggests is that the Qt module (QtBase, the base module), has not been registered and downloaded (they're stored as git submodules). IE, there is no makefile, nor anything else, in that directory.

Comment: i have the file "qt-everywhere-src-5.14.1.zip" already downloaded on my pc and it is using that
http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.14/5.14.1/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.14.1.zip

I can assure you that the makefile, and everything else, is in there @AlexanderHuszagh

Comment: Can you say what's actually in the qtbase directory?

Comment: Dir output posted in the question @AlexanderHuszagh. I appreciate you trying to help.

Comment: Thanks for posting that, and checking my local Qt5 seems to confirm an issue. I'm not seeing a Makefile, which I presume might be the issue. Can you try downloading a vanilla Qt5 using an installation method I'll share below. Let me get a full-running example up.

Comment: I've installed vanilla Qt5 using the binaries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209534/discussion-between-tomis13lack-and-alexander-huszagh).

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to use [Qt for Windows - Building from Source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html) - it may be more accurate.